# free boundary effect on Reynold equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I was trying to derive Reynolds equation in case of free boundary and no slip conditions.I know that derivation of reynolds equation requires the following assumption

1-constant viscosity

2-thin film geometry

3-negligible body force

4-no slip condition

So I was wondering what would be the effect of free boundary on reynolds equation.